# Espelhar pagina HTML com FRAMEs

Tags: html

Bom dia

é possivel controlar a mesma pagina html em dois pontos diferentes usando o FRAME?
tenho um formulario e gostaria de saber se posso inputar informacoes nele em dois pontos diferentes.

Comment: como ? explique melhor sua duvida

Answer (score -1):

Fiquei pensando na funcionalidade disso e bom, vamos tentar responder..

Primeiro vamos definir algumas coisas, que vejo que não estão bem claras, levando em consideração o tipo de pergunta.

**O que é HTML?**

HTML é uma linguagem de marcação, e serve basicamente para marcar elementos para indicar ao navegador o que ele deve exibir. No caso o html funciona e é compreendido pelo seu navegador. E ele por si só não "*conversa*" com um servidor ou com outro navegador ou máquina. São paginas estáticas.

**O que é FRAME?**

Frames são as divisões internas dentro de uma mesma janela do navegador, ou seja, você tem uma página comum, que possui divisões onde são carregadas `N` páginas. Geralmente para seu uso você possui uma pagina mãe, que chama as filhas.

Exemplo mais comuns de frames:

- 2 frames: [image: 2 frames] ou [image: 2 frames]
- 3 frames: [image: 3 frames] ou [image: 3 frames]

Portanto o frame não passa de `html`, se os dois pontos diferentes que você se refere for simplesmente as divisões, você até pode "inputar informações" de um divisão para a outra. Mas não com `html`, mas utilizando `js`.

Agora se você está falando de dois pontos serem tipo o meu e o seu `pc`, e o que eu mudar aqui alterar ai por exemplo, é ate possível de fazer também. Mas de novo, não somente com `html`, para fazer algo assim, pense mais ou menos na lógica ou formato de um chat. Onde eu digito aqui e aparece pra você em "*tempo real*".

No caso, tanto eu quanto você tem o `html` do chat pronto na tela, mas o chat precisa acessar alguma coisa que seja comum para os dois, que pode vir a ser um banco de dados ou simplesmente um arquivo `.txt` que contenha as mensagens. Mas eles precisam verificar alterações, talvez por `ajax`, e caso as encontre, recebe e altera o campo mensagem.

Seguindo mais ou menos essa lógica, no caso de um `form`, autocompletar de dois `pcs` diferentes, é possível. Porem você precisa de um lugar, arquivo ou base de dados, afim de compartilhar as informações. E sua aplicação precisa "*escutar*" esse arquivo, ou seja, verificar se existe alteração no mesmo feito por algum outro ponto (`pc`), caso exista, carregar na minha tela.

Isso seria uma forma básica, mas se tratando de um formulário, precisaria de algo mais elaborado, para que duas pessoas não alteram ao mesmo tempo o mesmo campo. Então esse "controle" da mesma página de dois pontos diferentes é possível de certo ponto, mas não sei se uma boa forma para se trabalhar. Depende muito do que você quer com isso.

Espero ter conseguido ajudar de alguma forma, qualquer dúvida pergunte.

Att;

Fontes:

[O que é html e para que serve?](http://tableless.com.br/o-que-html-basico/)

[HTML - Frames](http://www.ufpa.br/dicas/htm/htm-fra.htm)